# Use of regexprep in MATLAB to remove characters within parentheses in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, sorting, regexp-replace

I want to remove characters within parentheses from a string in MATLAB:

For eg: I have the string 
S(+42.01)DKHDKPDISEVTKFDKSKLKKTETHEKNPLPTKETIDQEKQG 
but want to remove the parentheses and store :
SDKHDKPDISEVTKFDKSKLKKTETHEKNPLPTKETIDQEKQG

The characters in parentheses could be text, numbers, combination of text numbers and special characters. Also the parentheses can occur multiple times in the same string.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There you go:

```
x = 'Q(-17.03)VAQMHVWRAVNHDRNHGTGSGRH(-.98)';
y = regexprep(x, '\([^\(\)]*\)',''); % detect substring formed by 
    % parentheses and anything in between that is not a parenthesis,
    % and replace that by an empty string
```

gives

```
y =
QVAQMHVWRAVNHDRNHGTGSGRH
```

Comment: Hi, this is almost right but I am not getting the right output when there are multiple parentheses. eg: 'Q(-17.03)VAQMHVWRAVNHDRNHGTGSGRH(-.98)' should give the output 'QVAQMHVWRAVNHDRNHGTGSGRH' but it just returns 'Q' and goes to the next step. Do you have any idea to fix it?